# Unprocessed expressions in an unrelated attribute on element that specifies a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this HTML with a `span` element that specifies a directive:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <span id="theSpan" my-directive="{{data.one}}" title="{{data.two}}">
</div>
```

The directive appends some HTML to the element:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: "<div>{{text}}</div>",
    scope: {
      text: "@myDirective"
    }
  };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    one: 'One!!',
    two: 'Two!!'
  };
}
```

This code results in the following DOM structure:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="ng-scope">
  <span id="theSpan" my-directive="One!!" title="" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope">
    <div class="ng-binding">One!!</div>
  </span>
</div>
```

The problem is the missing data from the `title` attribute on the `span`. I can get it to work correctly by adding `title: '@'` to the scope, like this:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: "<div>{{text}}</div>",
    scope: {
      text: "@myDirective",
      title: '@' // <-- added
    }
  };
});
```

which results in this DOM:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="ng-scope">
  <span id="theSpan" my-directive="One!!" title="Two!!" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope">
    <div class="ng-binding">One!!</div>
  </span>
</div>
```

How do I code my directive such that attributes on the element are preserved, without having to specify them in the directive's scope? (Perhaps a better question is: why isn't the `title` attribute being evaluated?)

Here is [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sEMeA/2/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I think you really should change the title. It is an interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by doing

```
scope: {
  text: "@myDirective"
}
```

you are creating an isolated scope for the span element. Thus, when `{{data.two}}` gets evaluated, there is no `data` property in the scope. The `'@myDirective'` allows that attribute to be evaluated and inserted into the isolated scope. That is  why the '@' works for the title. One solution could be to not use an isolated scope for the directive, and then use the `$observe` to set `text` in the scope of the directive. See http://jsfiddle.net/sEMeA/9/

Comment: Since the attribute is not related to the behavior of the directive, I have no way of knowing what attributes to check for and preserve manually--e.g., the `title` attribute should be left alone (along with any other attributes that may or may not be on the element).

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem is in the title attribute being cleared out. See my updated answer.